# How to apply different function to different columns using one apply method in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe **df** with three columns. Let's say the columns are **"A"**, **"B"** and **"C"**. And, I have three different functions **func1**, **func2** and **func3** which needs to be applied on column **A**, **B** and **C** respectively.

> **func1 -> column A**, **func2 -> column, B func3 -> column C**

```
df["A"].apply(lambda x: func1(x))
df["B"].apply(lambda x: func2(x))
df["C"].apply(lambda x: func3(x))
```

Here, I have to call three apply method on the three different columns. Is there any way to call the apply method once and run three different functions to three different columns instead of calling the apply method three times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your function returns a value for each row:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[1,2,3]})

df.transform({
    'A':lambda x: x-1,
    'B': lambda x: x+1,
    'C': lambda x: x*2
})
```

Output

```
   A  B  C
0  0  2  2
1  1  3  4
2  2  4  6
```

Comment: I've looked a lot for this answer, but most of my hits was with `groupby` so not that useful. Many thanks for sharing